# Alternative solutions for Skype in Linux?

Tags: linux

I used to use Skype on Windows for voice/chat/screensharing with my friends. On Linux however I found that Skype is at version 2.2 whereas the Windows version is 5.5! What the heck?

What are some alternative solutions for Skype in Linux? It'd be an advantage if it work with skype users.

Comment: Are you still going to need to connect to people running skype?

Comment: yes, that's the problem :(

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include that, it makes a big difference.

Comment: @nXqd: skype was bought by microsoft. i would not bet on any nearby improvement of the situation on linux. thus: convince your friends to not use skype. since skype is closed software with a pretty closed down protocol there are no real alternatives to the official skype client. maybe except the facebook chat :)

Comment: ok thanks, i think about it but I do some search but none of it work well with skype. So I'm thinking about a difference solution for us to work with when we do pair programming :)

Comment: +1 for 'What the heck?'!

Comment: The Linux version of Skype doesn't feature the latest GUI but for what I've seen it works ok. I'm not sure why you need alternatives: did you find something that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Is there a feature that you find in skype for Windows, that lacks in 2.2 for Linux that makes it unusable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there are other pieces of similar software to the best of my knowledge none of them can access the proprietary Skype network so cannot be used to chat with skype users.

Comment: yes, I've already searched a lot and right now I really want a MAC . It should solve the problem completely :(

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Skype's protocol is proprietary.  More [here](http://superuser.com/questions/75123/is-there-an-alternative-skype-client).

Comment: @nXqd you could build yourself a hackintosh if you're feeling brave ;-)

Comment: @Col: Already did it but laptop with GMA4500 and wifi 5100. Desktop with HD3600. I don't find any solution for them. I already think about building another desktop which can install hackintosh but it's for the future :P

Comment: @nXqd From what I've heard it's very picky about hardware but there are some good sites out there that list compatible kit if you're doing a scratch build.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [web version of Skype](https://www.skype.com/en/).

Also there is new alpha version of Skype for Linux .

https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299